# Eclipse 'Compare' menu options are all disabled

Tags: eclipse, svn, comparison

I recently upgraded my Subversion repository to version 1.6 and I'm connecting to it with Eclipse.  However, when I check out a project branch and try to compare it with a different revision, (or any other circumstances for that matter) all of the options for comparison are disabled except for comparing with the base revision of the current working copy.

Has anybody else encountered this, or possibly even found a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [bug 275287](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=275287), fixed in the [weekly builds](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/downloads.php#weekly_build) (reported as such back in July).

Since the latest release is the 0.7.8.I20090506-1500, from 04 September 2009, it may be also fixed in this official release as well.

So to be sure, you could complete your question with the exact version of eclipse / and subversive plugin version you are using.

Comment: You're right, I should have included that information to begin with. I'm currently using Subversive version 0.7.8.I20090506-1500 running on Eclipse 3.5.0.v20090611a

Comment: The problem's fixed in the 0.7.8.I20090903-1900 nightly build, thank you kindly for your help.